# Most elegant way to redirect to homepage in JSF

Tags: jsf, web-applications, redirect

in the upper left corner of my app there is a logo. After I click on it I would like to be redirecterd to home page wherever I am now. 
Of course I could just link it www.myhomepage.com but that is not very nice and scalable.
I could link it to action="../spring/main-flow" but that is not good either.
How should I do this properly?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Link to the context path directly:

```
<a href="#{request.contextPath}">...</a>
```

Or when you're still using old fashioned JSP as view technology:

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}">...</a>
```

*Works also in combination with `<h:outputLink>`.*

Or use the new JSF2 `<h:link>`, if you have for example a `index.xhtml`, it will prepend the context path automatically:

```
<h:link outcome="/index">...</h:link>
```

Comment: Exactly the answer I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Anything other than `/` seems overly complicated, unless different sub domains are involved.

Comment: The `/` will not work if the webapp is deployed on a context path. This server specific configuration setting is not controllable from inside the webapp. Hence my suggestion to link to the context path directly.